# Live server htaccess file configuration for vue js history mode

Tags: laravel

I upload my vuejs and laravel project on live server, after uploading i was facing the issue that my vue js history mode is not working so i read the documentation of html5 history mode and it gave the .htaccess code for server configuration, so i paste the code and after that i was facing the issue that my api is working but my frontend is not working.
This is my .htaccess code.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Serve index.html for all routes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Serve index.php for Laravel routes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api [NC]
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

my project structure is like this.
/Home/laravelProject
/public_html/(publicFolderFiles)
like: index.php index.html css jss folders.
my domain is this
https://www.web-tester.one
my api is working like this
https://www.web-tester.one/api/feeds
but my frontend is not working 404 error shown.
please help me, i also get confisued with chat gpt but i did not understand chat gpt, it
gave me so many codes but not working.

Comment: Is the Vue app separated from the SPA application or integrated with Laravel resources?

Comment: Yes, separated.